# private property giving error in python which is given in __init__

Tags: python, constructor, initialization, private-members

while evaluating `self.__properties` after `self.__properties = {}` line it is giving error

```
AttributeError("testPrivateVariable instance has no attribute '__properties'",),
```

Should be working, not sure what is wrong. Using python 2.6

```
import pdb
class testPrivateVariable:    
    size = 524288000    
    def __init__(self, default_properties=None):
        pdb.set_trace()
        self.__properties = {}
        self.__default_properties = {}
        if default_properties != None:
           self.__default_properties = default_properties
```

Comment: Nothing is going wrong. That's what's supposed to happen, the point of `__double_leading_underscore` is to invoke name mangling. Try accessing `_testPrivateVariable__properties`, or switch to `_single_leading_underscore`, which indicates private by convention.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but following code working 'class Class_demo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__properties = {}
        print("hi")
        print(self.__properties)
    a = "bsc"
    def sumFun(self, i, j):
        print(self.__properties)
        print( i+j)

# Class_demo.sumFun( Class_demo(),1, 2)
Class_demo().sumFun(3,4)'

Comment: Of course; when accessed via `self` inside the class the name gets mangled for every access.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, I was using only__double_leading_underscore without self.__double_leading_underscore , now it working. Got concept